# Livewire does not display data from database. Well it actually does if I dd the data

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

Following code does not display data. But if I dd the data it works

Livewire Company.php:

```
public $company;

public function mount(Company $company) {
    $this->company = $company;
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.company');
}
```

livewire.company:

```
<div>
{{$company->name}}</div>
```

Though if I dd $company->name it works

Web.php:

```
Route::livewire('/companies/{company}', 'company')->name('show-company');
```

layouts/app.blade.php:

```
@livewireStyles @livewire('company') <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script> @livewireScripts
```

Also if I don't use Route Model Binding but look for it like this

```
$this->company = Company::find($company);
```

it throws Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $company ]]

Comment: okay i need to know some things first. 1. what is your component blade's name ? 
2. when you dd inside mount(); , do you get any data ?

Comment: @fahim152 yes I do get data when I dd it inside of mount

Comment: what is your livewire blade file's name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are receiving a model in your mount function but when calling it from layouts/app.blade.php , you do not pass any argument.
So, Instead of

`@livewire('company')`

You can call something like:

`@livewire('company',['company' => App\Company::find(1)])`

Here I use my first instance of Company model but you can send what you need. But keep in mind that you should pass a model because you receive a model in mount().

Hope it'll work.